# Are balls around a point always symmetric about the axes?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, normed-spaces, symmetry, spheres

I think they are. And I have sketched the following proof so far.

> Every ball around the origin is symmetric to the X-axis (generalize to all axis and around all points)

Let $\| \cdot \|$ be any norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Say the set $\{t \in \mathbb{R}^n : \|t\| \neq \|t_x\|\}$ is non-empty, where $t_x$ is the reflection of $t$ about the $X-$axis. Let $r$ be "a" vector in the set with the smallest norm.

Clearly, $r \neq \underline 0$, so take the line joining $r$ and $\underline 0$. The function $\|\cdot\|$ is continuous everywhere in the ball of radius $\|r\|$, and this line is inside ball by its convexity. **Therefore $\|\cdot \|$ is continious on this line**, and assumes $0$ at $\underline 0$ and $\|r\|$ at $r$. Therefore by $IVT$, for every large enough $m$ there is a point $r_m$ on this line such that $\|r_m\| = \|r\| - \frac{1}{m}$. By the collinearity of $r, r_m$ and $\underline 0$, we have,
$$\|r-r_m\| = \|r\|-\|r_m\| = \frac{1}{m} \implies r_m \rightarrow r $$

Also, by continuity of reflection, we have $r_{m_x} \rightarrow r_x$, and by continuity of $\|\cdot\|$, we have $\|r_m\| \rightarrow \|r\|$, and $\|r_{m_x}\| \rightarrow \|r_x\|$.

Notice, by minimality of $r$, $\|r_m\| = \|r_{m_x}\|$; that is they are the same sequence, and hence must have the same limit. Hence, $\|r_x\| = \|r\|$. Contradiction! Or the set of assymetric vectors is non-empty.

---

I have the following concerns.

- Does the fact really hold? If no, where did I go wrong, and what is a counterexample?
- Assuming it does, the "lines" between two points $x$ and $y$ induced by a norm and by convexity might be different. Particularly, the set $\{tx + (1-t)y: 0\leq t \leq 1\}$ is always the straight line joining $x$ and $y$. However the set $\{z : \|y - z\| + \|z - x\| = \|y - x\|\}$ needn't always be a straight line. For example, it can be "L" shaped like in the case of $\|\cdot \|_1$ norm. Does this conflict affect the proof.
- Is there a simpler way to show this?

Comment: You can show that norms are symmetric about the origin and convex. You can also show that any set that is convex and symmetric about the origin can be used to define a norm by making it the unit circle and scaling. The proof should be accessible to you as an exercise.

Comment: Thank you. I know how to show the first part. I'll try to show the second part too.

Answer (score 22):

Your conjecture is wrong. $\Vert(x, y)\Vert = \max(|x|, |x+y|)$ is a norm on $\Bbb R^2$, but the ball $D = \{ (x, y) \mid \Vert(x, y)\Vert \le 1 \}$ is not symmetric with respect to the $x$-axis or $y$-axis:

[image]

(Image created with [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ecpfky8r8b).)

One problem in your argument is that the set $\{t \in \mathbb{R}^n : \|t\| \neq \|t_x\|\}$ is not closed, and therefore need not have an element with smallest norm.

Comment: Wow. This is brilliant. Thanks a lot for the answer.

Answer (score 8):

The balls of the Manhattan metric $|x|+|y|$ (i.e. the $L^1$ norm) in $\mathbb{R}^2$ are squares parallel to the coordinate axes (edit: actually, they're diagonal, so this is a diamond), which are not symmetric with respect to most othre axes. If you rotate this norm then the balls aren't even symmetric across the coordinate axes, or apply the right skew transformation and it isn't symmetric across any line. (Of course, symmetry across axes is interpreted with respect to the usual Euclidean metric, isn't it?)

Comment: Yes. So what i wanted is norm(x,y) = norm(-x,y). Just rotation wouldn't perhaps work because the norms of then points would change when their coordinates are changed. However, I have got a good counterexample to my conjecture in the other answer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @PritamChandra I don't understand your second sentence. If you take a square that is symmetric across the coordinate axes and rotate it by an angle that is not a multiple of $45^{\circ}$, it will no longer be symmetric across the coordinate axes. So yes, it would work: if you rotate the Manhattan metric to get a new norm, that new norm will not be symmetric across the coordinate axes.

Comment: So you're saying that if you rotate unit ball of the Manhattan metric by say 30 degrees, it won't stay symmetric about the original axes anymore. True. But then this rotated square wouldn't stay a unit ball wrt to the original axes, as the coordinates of the all the points have changed now. And the norm depends on the coordinates.

Comment: The rotated ball **would be** a ball with respect to the *rotated metric*! And Martin's example also illustrates the idea I'm presenting: his example is a skew transformation of the standard $L^{\infty}$ metric.

Comment: Oh. So you mean that the norm doesn't stay the manhattan norm anymore. Even the norm would have sin and cos components?

Comment: For rotations, yes. If $A$ is any invertible linear operator and $\|\vec{x}\|$ is any norm, then $\|A\vec{x}\|$ is also a norm. In particular, if $A$ is a $2\times2$ rotation matrix with $\theta=30^{\circ}$, the $L^1$ norm becomes $$ \left|\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}x-\frac{1}{2}y\right|+\left|\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}y\right|. $$ The balls of this metric are diamonds rotated $30^{\circ}$. The other answer's example is $\|A\vec{x}\|_{\infty}$ with $A=[\begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 \end{smallmatrix}]$.

Comment: Okay this makes total sense. Sorry about the earlier confusion. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hello, I now realize how beautiful this rotating norms are. I had a follow up question. Given any norm $||\cdot ||$, for a non singular matrix $A$, $||x||_* := ||Ax||$ is also a norm. Is the previous statement true?

Comment: Yep, it's true. Quick exercise. (I also stated that in my previous comment.)